# Consistency level error while trying to insert data to cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have the following cluster consisting of two node in two different datacenters:

```
Datacenter: 168
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Token                                    Rack
UN  10.168.92.13    47.44 KB   100.0%            70e6fb88-60d3-4f19-b4a7-4eacc6790042  -9223372036854775808                     92
Datacenter: 186
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Token                                    Rack
UN  10.186.163.119  73.33 KB   100.0%            19714869-3d7a-434b-9c41-e7d90f14205c  0                                        163
```

I created a keyspace using NetworkTopologyStrategy to spread the data among the nodes. Assuming this will make a replica of the data in every datacenter, like this:

```
Create KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','DC1':1,'DC2':1};
```

Then I made a simple table user (id,name,last_name) but when I try to import or insert data to it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/cqlsh", line 1108, in perform_simple_statement
    rows = self.session.execute(statement, trace=self.tracing_enabled)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.7.2.zip/cassandra-driver-2.7.2/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1602, in execute
    result = future.result()
  File "/home/ubuntu/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.7.2.zip/cassandra-driver-2.7.2/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3347, in result
    raise self._final_exception
Unavailable: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve consistency level ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 0, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

I also set in cassandra.yaml file `endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch`

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the datacenters that appear when using nodetool status must match the names of the dcs when defining the keyspace strategy, for example:

```
Create KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','DC1':1,'DC2':1};
```

should be:

```
Create KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','168':1,'186':1};
```

Either that or renaming the datacenters to DC1 and DC2 and executing node repair.